# why is there lag when i add image?

Tags: java, android, lag

i recently have been experiencing with lag when i run my program, one of my activity has 7 images and im planning to add more however when i start to scroll down the whole thing lags, i dont know if its because of the action bar that i have hidden in the xml(i hid it because i dont know how to remove it from the activity), im hoping that you guys can tell me how to fix this issue (lag issue).

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".EX" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="688dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/border"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/greenborder" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ss" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cht" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ags" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/as" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ly" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView6"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/co" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:text="Select a category:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/fy" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView7"
        android:text="More available soon"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

logcat:

06-30 18:05:24.908: E/LocSvc_IzatApiV02(584): W/virtual int izat_core::IzatApiV02::injectLocation(GpsExtLocation):665]: error! inject position failed

06-30 18:05:24.918: E/LocSvc_ApiV02(584): W/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiV02::injectPosition(double, double, float):492]: error! status = eLOC_CLIENT_FAILURE_INVALID_PARAMETER, inject_pos_ind.status = UNKNOWN

06-30 18:05:24.968: I/GCoreUlr(6145): Successfully inserted location

06-30 18:05:24.968: I/GCoreUlr(6145): Not calling LocationReportingService, hasMoved: false, elapsed millis: 2176457, request: Phone

06-30 18:05:28.802: I/Choreographer(8748): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

06-30 18:05:29.483: I/Choreographer(8748): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

06-30 18:05:30.154: I/Choreographer(8748): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

06-30 18:05:30.834: I/Choreographer(8748): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

06-30 18:05:31.495: I/Choreographer(8748): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

06-30 18:05:32.166: I/Choreographer(8748): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: Can you post your logcat when the lag appears?

Comment: This is maybe due to the images that you are using very heavy images which are taking time to load. Kindly post some code.

Comment: i have added the logcat when the lag appears, how do i fix this?

Comment: What is the resolution of your images?

Comment: 300 are you suggesting i lower it if so to how much would you advise me to lower it whist giving the image a good quality

Comment: I think that's your problem! Try to lower those measurements on your images!

Comment: what do you suggest i lower it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain things you can do for your lag issues:

You can scale down your pictures.

1. For this I would strongly recommend reading this [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
2. Make a new folder in your res folder named drawable-nodpi and move all your png(your images) resources there!
3. Resize your images from 2048 x 2048 to a lower resolution.

Comment: so instead of putting my images and resorses in the other drawable i should just place them here, sorry i like being very specific

Comment: The drawable-nodpi folder contains resources for all densities(density independent resources).

Comment: it only reduced the lag i chnaged it to 1000x1000